# Recursive multiplication

Tags: oracle-12c

How can I get ASSY_EXT_QTY to be the quantity of all the path?
IE:

```
LVL   QTY   ASSY_EXT_QTY
1     1     1
2     3     3 1*3
3     2     6 1*3*2
...
```

I thought making a path but for the quantities and then somehow multiply them but this seems far reached. This is the code:

```
select
  LEVEL,
  SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(CHILD_ITEM_NUMBER, '>') ROUTE,
  CASE
    LEVEL
    WHEN 1 THEN COMPONENT_QTY
    ELSE (PRIOR COMPONENT_QTY) * COMPONENT_QTY <--- RIGHT NOW I'M DOING THIS BUT NOT ENOUGH AS WORKS IN THE CURRENT SUB-LEVEL ONLY.
  END ASSY_EXT_QTY
from
  (
    select
...
    FROM
...
    WHERE
...
  ) START WITH FATHER_ITEM_NUMBER = :ASSY CONNECT BY PRIOR CHILD_ITEM_ID = STR_ITEM_ID
) bom
```

I'd be just SQL, no functions or something like that as I'm not allowed by the environment.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

## ODCI

Personally, I'd probably write my own aggregate function so that the SQL looks like

```sql
select
  SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(CHILD_ITEM_NUMBER, '>') ROUTE,
  my_mult_agg( ) over (order by level) ASSY_EXT_QTY
from ( .. ) bom
```

(There still might be a pure SQL way)

## Example:

Modified from the example in the documentation found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28425/aggr_functions.htm)

```sql
create or replace
type my_mult_agg_impl as object
(
  mult_buffer NUMBER, -- highest value seen so far 
  static function ODCIAggregateInitialize(sctx IN OUT my_mult_agg_impl) 
    return number,
  member function ODCIAggregateIterate(self IN OUT my_mult_agg_impl, 
    value IN number) return number,
  member function ODCIAggregateDelete(self IN OUT my_mult_agg_impl, 
    value IN number) return number,
  member function ODCIAggregateTerminate(self IN my_mult_agg_impl, 
    returnValue OUT number, flags IN number) return number,
  member function ODCIAggregateMerge(self IN OUT my_mult_agg_impl, 
    ctx2 IN my_mult_agg_impl) return number
);
/

create or replace type body my_mult_agg_impl is 
static function ODCIAggregateInitialize(sctx IN OUT my_mult_agg_impl) 
return number is 
begin
  sctx := my_mult_agg_impl(1);
  return ODCIConst.Success;
end;

member function ODCIAggregateIterate(self IN OUT my_mult_agg_impl, value IN number) return number is
begin
  mult_buffer := mult_buffer * value;
  
  return ODCIConst.Success;
end;
member function ODCIAggregateDelete(self IN OUT my_mult_agg_impl, value IN number) return number is
begin
  mult_buffer := mult_buffer / value;
  
  return ODCIConst.Success;
end;

member function ODCIAggregateTerminate(self IN my_mult_agg_impl, 
    returnValue OUT number, flags IN number) return number is
begin
  returnValue := mult_buffer;
  return ODCIConst.Success;
end;
member function ODCIAggregateMerge(self IN OUT my_mult_agg_impl, ctx2 IN my_mult_agg_impl) return number is
begin
  self.mult_buffer := self.mult_buffer * ctx2.mult_buffer;
  
  return ODCIConst.Success;
end;
end;
/

CREATE or replace FUNCTION my_mult_agg (input NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER 
AGGREGATE USING my_mult_agg_impl;
/

select level,
 my_mult_agg( level ) over (order by level) as MM
from dual
connect by level <= 10
order by level;
```

result:

[image: result of SELECT statement]

Comment: Thanks Michael! Saddly I do not have access to creating functions. I'm working in a Cloud environment without direct access to DB. I'd have put that in the OP.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old trick for multiplying rows instead of summing them:

```
drop table t1 purge;
create table t1 (lvl number, qty number);
insert into t1 values (1, 1);
insert into t1 values (2, 3);
insert into t1 values (3, 4);
insert into t1 values (4, 2);
insert into t1 values (5, 3);
commit;
select * from t1;

       LVL        QTY
---------- ----------
         1          1
         2          3
         3          4
         4          2
         5          3

select
 lvl, qty,
 round(exp(sum(ln(qty)) over (order by lvl))) as assy_ext_qty
from
  t1;

       LVL        QTY ASSY_EXT_QTY
---------- ---------- ------------
         1          1            1
         2          3            3
         3          4           12
         4          2           24
         5          3           72
```

Beware of fractions and rounding.